# Why Call Of Duty 4 : Modern Warfare multiplayer disappears whenever I join a server?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

Whenever I start Call Of Duty:Modern Warfare multiplayer, it runs perfectly but whenever I join a server it starts to download a mod and stops at 61% or 96% and shows setting up game then it loads but when the loading is done, it suddenly disappears and I come back to desktop? Anyone who can help me out there?

Answer (score 0):

1. wait for some minutes (max 15min)
2. if the above option didn't work try another server, if other servers work, the problem is not with your end.
3. if none of the above worked, try installing cod4x in cod4x.me and then you can easily join servers based on cod4x which is a great non-official update (as they say, v1.8) and it works quite good.
4. if again none of the above worked, try installing Garena or Gameranger so you can play online there